# Log in / Log Out Custom Button

Tags: php, functions, login, code

On our website we have a "Join" button in the top right corner and a log in / log out link using `<?php wp_loginout(); ?>` . Instead of having the log in / log out link we would like to have it display in a button. It should ready "Login" when something like `if ( is_user_logged_in() )` is false and "Log Out" when it's true.

The Code for the Join Button is:

```
<a href="www.google.com" class="join-button">Join</a>
```

so the code for the Log in / log out button should have the same `.join-button` class.

Style for `.join-button`:

```
.join-button {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f5840c;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f5840c;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f5840c;
background-color:#f5840c;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
border:1px solid #f5840c;
display:inline-block;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
padding: 1px 4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #f5840c;
}
```

Could someone please help me write the code to achieve this task?

Answer (score 4):

here is a very simple function that should do it:

```
function loginout_button_wpa89153($echo = true){
    if (is_user_logged_in()){
        $url = wp_logout_url(get_permalink());
        $anchor = "Logout";
    }else{
        $url = wp_login_url(get_permalink());
        $anchor = "Login";
    }
    $button = '<a href="'.$url.'" class="join-button">'.$anchor.'</a>';
    if ($echo)
        echo $button;
    else
        return $button;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your work with that, however, it's not displaying anything on my end.

Comment: did you call it?

Comment: @Patrick instead of <?php wp_loginout(); ?> replace it with <?php loginout_button_wpa89153(); ?>